# Delegating access to Gmail Account doesn't work

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email

I know that Gmail supports a way to [delegate access to your email](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350?hl=en) account. However, when I go into Gmail settings, I do not see the option to delegate access (screenshot below).

I am using Google Apps—is that the reason? If so, how do I enable email delegation?

[image: gmail screenshot]

Comment: I am the domain administrator.  How do I enable mail delegation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out!  It's burried in a bunch of sub-menus:

1. Log into your [Google Apps account](http://apps.google.com)
2. Click "Users" in the dashboard
3. Click a user's name
4. Click Google Apps Enabled
5. Click Gmail
6. Click User Settings
7. Scroll down and check the "Mail Delegation" checkbox half-way down the screen.

Wasn't that easy?

[image: Delegate access to gmail]

Comment: Actually it's not that easy. Setting that checkbox doesn't cause an immediate change. "These changes may take up to 1 hour to propagate to all users." The fact that the option is hidden and doesn't show up right away makes this super hard and frustrating.

Comment: For me, the option took a few minutes to show up, but when I click the "Add another account" button it comes up with a blank pop up and doesn't do anything.  (I only set it up 15 minutes ago)

Answer (score 1):

- If you are part of a Google Workspace organization you will need the admin to enable mail delegation in the admin console

`Apps > Google Workspace > Settings for Gmail > User Settings`

The part that solved it for me:

After enabling this feature make sure to refresh your cache or login with incognito to see the new settings. I waited for 24 hours without it appearing but this solved the issue.